# Does Eclipse support building PreferenceScreen?

Tags: android, eclipse

When you are about to build regular activity you have simple builder in Eclipse (actually a plugin) for that. Is there anything like that for `PreferenceScreen`? And if yes, how to activate it?

Comment: afaik, You can not see the preview of the preferenc screen but when you will eidt the Preference xml file and if you type initial string of the tab or property and if you press cntl + space then it will give you hint.

Comment: Thank you. A "no" is still a valuable answer, so please post it as such (answer) so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, there is no any option to see the graphical layout of the Preference activity but like xml layout eclipse provide the facility for edit the xml file of the Preference activity.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a WYSIWYG editor but Eclipse's Android tools come with a *Preference Screen* editor, which is far more powerful than a simple XML editor:

`New` → `Other` → `Android XML File` → Click `Next` → Select `Preference` as `Resource Type`, change the `Root Element` to `Preference Screen` and enter a file name. Done